# How to display Model Relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this database table: `job`, `department`, `pcn` and this table `pcn` has properties `job_id` and `department_id` on it. So in Laravel I have this definitions on its equivalent models:

```php
class Job extends Model
{
    public function pcns(){return $this->hasMany('App\Pcn', 'id');}
}
```

```php
class Department extends Model
{
    public function pcns(){return $this->hasMany('App\Pcn', 'id');}
}
```

```php
class Pcn extends Model
{
    public function job(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Job');}

    public function department(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');}
}
```

My problem now is my pcn index that displays list of Pcn is giving me this error:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\bookersystem\resources\views\pcn\index.blade.php)
```

in which my `index.blade.php` has this:

```php
@foreach($pcns as $key => $value)
    <td>{{ $value->control_number }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->job->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->department->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

On my Pcn controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $pcns = Pcn::paginate(50);

    return view('pcn.index', compact('pcns'));

}
```

As for my migrations i have this difinition:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pcn', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
        //$table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('department');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('job_id');
        //$table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('job');
        $table->string('control_number', 45);
        $table->string('center', 5);
        $table->string('status', 8)->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('mrf_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('degree', 25)->default('Not Recruiting');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide code from your controller

Comment: I have updated my post and add some controller.

Comment: Should be `@foreach($pcns as $pcn)` then `$pcn->job->name`.

Comment: I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firt thing it's better to remove the `id` from the relationships definition or declare the **right** `foreign key`:

```php
class Job extends Model
{
    //this
    public function pcns(){return $this->hasMany('App\Pcn');}
    //or this
    public function pcns(){return $this->hasMany('App\Pcn', 'job_id', 'id');}
}

class Department extends Model
{
    //this
    public function pcns(){return $this->hasMany('App\Pcn');}
    //or this 
    public function pcns(){return $this->hasMany('App\Pcn', 'department_id', 'id');}
}
```

Second step: it's better to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships to reduce the number of queries needed:

```php
public function index()
{
    $pcns = Pcn::with(['job', 'department'])->paginate(50);

    return view('pcn.index', compact('pcns'));
}
```

After that in your view you don't really need `$key=>$value` in the `@foreach`:

```php
@foreach($pcns as $pcn)
    <td>{{ $pcn->control_number }}</td>
    <td>{{ $pcn->job->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $pcn->department->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sir do i need to add constraint/foreign (mysql) as in ```ADD CONSTRAINT `pcns_department_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `pcns_job_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `job` (`id`);``` key on the database layer? because i am still getting null.

Comment: You don't need to add constraints for the relationships to work. Please post the migrations in your question.

Comment: I added my migration up functions for the model Pcn.

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling the name property of other object not in the @foreach in your view?

Comment: Yes sir, on my ```department``` table i have property name and so ```job``` table and throughout the page i only use that properties.

Comment: try to reduce the view to only the @foreach statement, remove all other things

Comment: Now it works as i uncomments my ```$table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('department');``` and ```$table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('job');```. Thank you very much for the help sir, infact i am very new to this frameworks and PHP langauge.

Answer (score 1):

`paginate()` method does not return a collection of `Pcn`, it return a `LengthAwarePaginator`, when turned into an array, it has as indexes (`total`, `per_page`, `next_link`....)

You need to recover the Collection from the `LengthAwarePaginator`

```
@foreach($pcns as $pcn)
    <td>{{ $pcn->control_number }}</td>
    <td>{{ $pcn->job->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $pcn->department->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

By the way, you should preload the `job` and `department` relations in your query to only send **3 requests** to the database instead of **101**.

```
$pcns = Pcn::with(['job', 'department'])->paginate(50);
```

Comment: You dont need to iterate over `$pcns->items()`, from the laravel docs: _the paginator instances are iterators and may be looped as an array_.

Comment: @dparoli that's true, have you tried with preloaded relation (`with(['job', 'department'])`) ?